# interpreter->typed_input_tensor issues with uchar variables

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, tensorflow-lite

I have issue with fill input of tensorflow-lite model.

First stage of my model takes uchar variables but:

```cpp
//seg falut
    interpreter_stage1->typed_input_tensor<uchar>(0)[i] = 0;

//works good
    interpreter_stage1->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[i] = 0;
```

I don't undestand why I cannot why uchar type is not working properly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer if someone will face a similiar issue.

When I printed interpretetState

```cpp
tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());
```

I saw that model which was previously moved from Keras to TFLite has different input type than expected. It looks like it is waiting for Float32 not uchar type.

```sh
Interpreter has 26 tensors and 11 nodes
Inputs: 9
Outputs: 16

Tensor   0 conv2d_1/BiasAdd     kTfLiteFloat32  kTfLiteArenaRw    3154176 bytes ( 3.0 MB)  1 222 222 16
(...)
```